# How to find processed called from a specific Terminal?

Tags: command-line, process

I sometimes start processes in the background using the terminal. For example:

```
$ matlab &
```

Some hours later, I cannot remember which Terminal I began matlab from, i.e. which Terminal is not safe to close.

How can I check in a Terminal to see what child processes it has spawned (if any)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jobs` command will list all background jobs launched from the shell you type it in.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way (apart from [Dennis's answer](https://askubuntu.com/users/945/dennis-kaarsemaker)) is with the well-known and widely used command:

```
ps -e -o pid,ppid,args --forest
```

Then you can see quickly the pid of the terminal that has launched various processes, and the processes themselves:

```
 3494  3490  \_ gnome-pty-helper
 3495  3490  \_ bash
 3566  3495  |   \_ evince
 3578  3490  \_ bash
 3684  3578  |   \_ man ps
 3693  3684  |       \_ pager -s
 3709  3490  \_ bash
 3801  3709      \_ /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/meld
 3871  3709      \_ ps -e -o pid,ppid,args --forest
```

For a particular terminal, enter `ps -T` in that terminal:

```
 PID  SPID TTY          TIME CMD
 3709  3709 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
 3801  3801 pts/3    00:00:00 meld
 3882  3882 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
```

For more information on `ps`, see `man ps` or the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ps.1posix.html). There are some very interesting and extremely useful `ps` combinations that can be made. I was inspired by some of the examples [in this article](http://www.pixelbeat.org/cmdline.html), and continue to experiment with different combinations.

Comment: Definitely an interesting command, but probably overkill for my use! Could come in handy in the future.